# Using custom Pipeline for Cross Validation scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to be use GridSearchCV to determine the parameters of a classifier, and using pipelines seems like a good option.

The application will be for image classification using Bag-of-Word features, but the issue is that there is a different logical pipeline depending on whether training or test examples are used.

For *each* training set, KMeans must run to produce a vocabulary that will be used for testing, but for test data no KMeans process is run.

I cannot see how it is possible to specify this difference in behavior for a pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to derive from the `KMeans` class and override the following methods to use your vocabulary logic:

- `fit_transform` will only be called on the train data
- `transform` will be called on the test data

Maybe class derivation is not alway the best option. You can also write your own transformer class that wraps calls to an embedded KMeans model and provides the `fit` / `fit_transform` / `transform` API that is expected by the `Pipeline` class for the first stages.

Comment: Ah, I think that might be the piece I was missing, I knew there had to be a way to perform different behavior depending on test/train. Thanks